# Best strategy to get a refund from Delta?

Tags: refunds, delta-air-lines

After checking in 90 minutes before my flight from Tokyo, the immigration held me for 2 hours to fix some paperwork, and I missed my flight home. Immigration had me then change my ticket on Delta for the next one and I paid $2k for the change. The original ticket was around $1k. So total is $3k.

I called Delta multiple times, but they refused to refund any of the extra $2k paid. What will be the best way to get refund for the extra amount paid?

It is not fair for Delta to take advantage of this situation to make this unreasonable amount of profit.

Comment: https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/check-in/requirements.html   "The recommended arrival time at the airport prior to departure of international flights is 3 hours."

Comment: When you bought your original ticket, it had some terms & conditions – which you probably didn't read, because, well, who does, right? And these T&A ruled, among other things, the conditions for ticket change and cancelation. Read them [again]. They probably say that you need to pay X. Or that change is not allowed. Which meant you had to buy a new ticket. One-way. Last-minute. And Delta is not at fault.

Comment: They held you on departure or arrival?

Comment: You're not going to get anything out of Delta. Just take the loss. It's unfortunate however you have little recourse. You should have let immigration change the flight themselves which they probably could.

Comment: why did immigration force you to change the ticket?  Usually, if you miss a flight, the airline will try to put you on the next flight that they can, without having to pay extra.  I have to agree with others though, since you've already paid for the change, there's probably not much recourse in terms of getting a refund.

Answer (score 3):

**Delta did not cause you to be late.** Delta had no control over whether you were late or not. Therefore Delta has no responsibility to refund you money for a problem that was outside their control - any more than they would be responsible if you checked in late because your bus was late or your car broke down.

The people who caused your lateness were you (for not checking in at the recommended time) or immigration - but immigration were almost certainly just doing their job and not at fault.

Sometimes stuff just happens.

Comment: The probably likely is that OP 'voluntarily' changed the ticket, to Delta at least.  Why, Delta doesn't care.  OP probably would have been better off just missing the flight, then going to the counter and explaining, with paperwork, the immigration hold, then get reaccommodated on some other flight.